# Wordpress - prevent auto <p> in TinyMce

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am using ACF, and using TinyMCE Advanced plugin.

When editing posts, the editor inserts new links into p tags, which I am trying to prevent as I am using the code tag and if there is a return within the code within the code tag, it wraps it in a new p and code block that then breaks the layout of the post.

I have tried playing with the plugin settings to check to remove the p tags, however no luck.

I have searched and found that I should be setting forced root block to false, however I am still unable to get it to work:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', function ($init) {

        //Prevent <p> tags in editor
        $init['forced_root_block'] = false;
        $init['force_br_newlines'] = false;
        $init['force_p_newlines'] = false;
        $init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = false;

        return $init;
    });
```

When viewing the post in Text tab, the code shows no P tags, however when editing within the visual tab, its breaking it all out into p tags.

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

When you output the content, while in a loop, you can sanitize the output to remove any and all tags using `wp_strip_all_tags`.

> Properly strip all HTML tags including script and style.

```
<?php wp_strip_all_tags( the_content(), true ); ?>
```

(`true` or `false` for line breaks). Same thing for ACF, just englobe the output in it.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/

Alternatively, you can remove any auto `<p>` tag applied as line break by removing the `wpautop` via `remove_filter` in your `function.php` file.

```
<?php remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); ?>
```

And with an ACF editor WYSIWYG/TinyMCE

```
<?php remove_filter ( 'acf_the_content', 'wpautop' ); ?>
```

Comment: is it possible to remove_filter an ACF field?